# Name that frame! (Likely Japanese, likely made in 1986, with known serial number, likely a Bianchi)

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

*(This post was substanically edited/updated on 5/8/14.)*

I have a bike frame of unknown lineage.

What is known:

- The serial number under the bottom bracket is IS513786. This fits with the serial numbers for Japanese made Bianchis.
- The frame has Shimano EF rear dropouts that are stamped with 'IJ'. That [means](http://www.vintage-trek.com/component_dates.htm#shimano) they were made in October 1984.
- Although I can't be sure that the fork is original, the steering tube has "Tange.5.I" and a 'J' and 'S' in a circle stamped on it. Also, the crown race was originally JIS sized.
- I got the bare frame, not the complete bike, and the paint is not original.

The dropouts were made in late '84 and we now know that the last two digits of the serial number do not represent the year. (E.g., [this](http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/808726-newest-ride-japanese-bianchi.html) **'89** Japanese Bianchi has a serial number ending in **86**.) So the frame is likely from a '84 or '85 Bianchi (since the dropouts were made late in '84).

FWIW, I've posted pictures below; I've made sure to point out things that could help identify the frame (braze-ons, lug style, etc.). I've tried to arrange the pictures with the most identifying characteristics first.

FWIW, [Here](http://www.pedalroom.com/bike/bianchi-brava-9734) is a similar looking, but not identical, 1986 Bianchi Brava. (That Bianchi has the chainstay cable stop on the underside, while my bike has the cable stop on top.)

(I posted this information on a couple bike forums a few years ago. If you want to see what people said, here are the links to the two threads on [bikeforums.net](http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/645681-name-frame.html) and [roadbikereview.com](http://forums.roadbikereview.com/retro-classic/name-frame-212595-post2782128.html).)

**The bottom of the bottom bracket, including the serial number. Also note that there is a chainstay bridge.**
[image: Headtube]

**The front of the headtube front. Note that the lugs have points in the middle (unlike some other Japanese lugs from that era).**
[image: Headtube front]

**The Shimano EF rear, drive-side dropout. Note that there are no eyelets. The date stamp is on the back side, so it is not shown.**
[image: Drive side dropout]

**The top of the seat stay cap has a flat surface and has nothing written on it. (Some bikes, like high end Miyatas, have curved caps and/or the company name cast into the caps.)**
[image: Seat cluster]

**The head tube has a pump peg.**
[image: Back of headtube]

***EDIT*: The whole frame:**
[image]

**The side of the bottom bracket:**
[image: bottom bracket side]

**The frame's downtube shifter mounts:**
[image: Downtube shifter mounts]

**The seat stays have a chain hanger.** *Edit: it's hard to see, but the chainstay cable stop is on top of the chainstay -- not below it.*
[image: Seat stays]

**The fork:**
[image: Fork]

Comment: Most serial number conventions I've seen have the first numeric denoting age, so likely an 85. Don't know the make but at least you can narrow to companies that were working with Shimano at the time in Japan.

Comment: Can we also have a full frame picture?

Comment: I've added a picture of the whole frame. Unfortunately, narrowing it down to Japanese companies that used Shimano in '85 or '86 doesn't do much; there are a lot of companies that did. A few companies (like Miyata) noted the dropout manufactures in their catalog, but they're the exception. In short, that narrows things from a huge haystack to a very large haystack. If someone could just point out one manufacturer who use a similar serial number scheme, that would be huge.

Comment: Here's a lead. Apparently a Japanese made Bianchi had the serial number "DS484284", and it was identified as being made in 1984. http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/70572-bianchi-serial-number-identification.html Now I just need to find a 1986 Bianchi catalog...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a _full_ 1986 Bianchi catalog. Maybe this 1986 Bianchi Brava looks very similar: http://www.pedalroom.com/bike/bianchi-brava-9734 Unfortunatly, I can't see the lugs on the headtube well enough to tell if it has a point in the middle. Also, it has a different fork, but that doesn't mean as much.

Comment: Nothing particularly distinctive -- looks a lot like my old Nishiki frame, only that had cantis and fender/rack eyelets.  The lugs look pretty much stock for medium quality bikes of that era.

Comment: I know it's not a custom Italian frame made from 0.1 um thick steel tubes blessed by the Pope, but I still want to know what it is. Moreover, I'd put it above medium quality. The lack of eyelets alone shows the manufacture didn't intend it for grocery runs. The frame weighs a hair under 5 lbs, which isn't bad considering it's a ~63cm steel frame from the '80s; from what I've seen, that's comparable to the high end steel frames of the day.

Comment: There seems to be a number of Japan Bianchis online from a similar time with a 2 alpha 2 number format of s_____ with an alpha in front of the S and 6 numbers after. No IS but JS, AS and CS. I think your probably on the right track, especially with the pump peg on the head tube.

Comment: Although not the same model the frame in this article certainly shares many of the same characteristics including the serial number: http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/498479-question-bianchi-cognoscenti.html

Comment: This is an excellent "identify my bike" question IMO. Photos, and you've typed in the text you have to make the question more searchable. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Does anyone know which Japanese company (or companies) made the frames for Bianchi?

Comment: By "medium quality" I meant a step up from the first rung of "real" bikes.  My Nishiki was a touring bike (hence the cantis and eyelets, and it also had a pump peg), and had an integral derailer hanger and sculpted lugs similar to your pictures.  Unless you can match up the serial number I doubt that you can do much better than Japanese, mid 80s.

Comment: Try contacting Bianchi via email (bianchi@bianchi.com) to confirm your serial number and ask them where or who built the frame, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: My understanding is that they can't help: http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/70572-bianchi-serial-number-identification.html#post672783

Comment: First, respect! For trying to identify this bike for at least four years http://forums.roadbikereview.com/retro-classic/name-frame-212595.html. I spent a while looking and, while the serial number points towards Bianchi, the pointy head tube lugs do not -- Bianchi, then and now, almost always had a clean head tube for the big Eduardo Bianchi logo. This site http://forums.roadbikereview.com/retro-classic/japanese-bianchis-questions-161417.html lists Limited; Brava; and the Sport SX as the three Ishiwata (Japanese steel) frames of the 80s. Pictures of all three show no-point head tube lugs.

Comment: Thanks for the props. I have seen the pointy lugs on at least one Japanese Bianchi: http://www.pedalroom.com/p/bianchi-brava-9734_3.jpg I still haven't identified the frame though. Regardless, I recently had the frame powdercoated, and I'll gradually build it up.

Comment: Here's a 1989 Brava with an "IS" serial number (also ending in "86", interestingly). The photo is hard to see but I think might have pointy head lugs. Fork is uni instead of lugged though. http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/808726-newest-ride-japanese-bianchi.html

Comment: Good catch on the serial number! Also, it looks like I can't read: Shimano date code IJ means October 1984 -- not 1985. So it's good to know that the last two digits of the serial number probably aren't the year.

Comment: What's on the sticker down by the bottom bracket?

Comment: It's a registration sticker for using the bike on a college campus; it's not original.

Answer (score 3):

I have a KATAKURA SILK bike with serial number IS514477. Your serial number is very similar. Maybe your bike is a KATAKURA bike.

Comment: Nice find, welcome to the site!  Do you have photos of your bike to [edit] into the answer?  Could be useful as a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I think i may have the answer to your question. I believe your bicycle is a Takara.  This is currently my girlfriends bike, and i have attached some photos.  The only things that do not match up are: 1) The front of the head-tube does does not have pointed lugs.

[image: Bottom Bracket]

[image: Head Tube]

[image: Drive Side Dropout]

[image: Head Tube with Pump Peg]

[image: Bottom Bracket]

[image: Left Side shifter mount]

[image: Chain Hanger, and chain stay cable stop on top of chain stay]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, it isn't conclusive since I believe that Takara is a brand, not a manufacturer. For example, some of Takara's bikes were made by Kawamura (according to wikipedia), and Kawamura may also have made bikes for Bianchi.

Comment: Please tell me that rear wheel was out for the photos?  The axle positioning looks particularly bad, I hope its not ridden like that.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the serial number is the same as certain models of Katakura Silk.

The Katakura Silk serial numbers tend to be stamped on the lower seat tube, non-drive side.

The lugs, seat stay caps, fork crown and dropouts match the Katakura Silk.

Some of the Katakuras were chrome finished, some were white, and possibly other colours.